# How to create new columns by looping through columns in different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two `pd.dataframes`:

df1:

```
Year      Replaced   Not_replaced
2015       1.5         0.1
2016       1.6         0.3
2017       2.1         0.1
2018       2.6         0.5
```

df2:

```
Year       HI      LO     RF
2015       3.2     2.9    3.0
2016       3.0     2.8    2.9
2017       2.7     2.5    2.6
2018       2.6     2.2    2.3
```

I need to create a third `df3` by using the following equation:

```
df3[column1]=df1['Replaced']-df1['Not_replaced]+df2['HI']
df3[column2]=df1['Replaced']-df1['Not_replaced]+df2['LO']
df3[column3]=df1['Replaced']-df1['Not_replaced]+df2['RF']
```

I can merge the two dataframes and manually create 3 new columns one by one, but I can't figure out how to use the loop function to create the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty dataframe & fill it with values while looping

(Note: `col_names` & `df3.columns` must be of the same length)

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['column1','column2','column3'])
col_names = ["HI", "LO","RF"]
for incol,df3column in zip(col_names,df3.columns):
    df3[df3column] = df1['Replaced']-df1['Not_replaced']+df2[incol]
print(df3)
```

**output**

```
column1     column2    column3
0   4.6     4.3        4.4
1   4.3     4.1        4.2
2   4.7     4.5        4.6
3   4.7     4.3        4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

for the for loop, I would first merge df1 and df2 into to create a new df, called df3. Then, I would create a list of te names of the columns you want to iterate through:

col_names = ["HI", "LO","RF"]

```
for col in col_names:
     df3[f"column_{col}]= df3['Replaced']-df3['Not_replaced]+df3[col]
```